# Fortran code freezes when using mpi_send on an HPC but not on my laptop

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have a subroutine that is supposed to mix values in an array `W % R` between different processors using `MPI_SEND`. It works on my laptop (in the sense it doesn't crash) with both Intel and gfortran compilers. But when I run it on an HPC the program freezes the first time the subroutine is called.

```
SUBROUTINE mix_walkers( W ) 

 include 'mpif.h'
 TYPE(walkerList), INTENT(INOUT) :: W
 INTEGER, SAVE :: calls = 0
 INTEGER :: ierr, nthreads, rank, width, self, send, recv, sendFrstWlkr, sendLstWlkr, sendWlkrcount, &
            recvFrstWlkr, recvlstWlkr, recvWlkrcount, status

  calls = calls + 1

  CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_WORLD, nthreads, ierr )

  CALL MPI_COMM_RANK ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr )

  width = W % nwlkr / nthreads

  IF( MODULO( calls, nthreads ) == 0 ) calls = calls + 1

  send          = MODULO( rank + calls, nthreads )
  recv          = MODULO( rank - calls, nthreads )

  sendFrstWlkr  = width * send + 1 
  recvFrstWlkr  = width * recv + 1 

  sendLstWlkr   = MIN( sendFrstWlkr - 1 + width, W % nwlkr )
  recvlstWlkr   = MIN( recvFrstWlkr - 1 + width, W % nwlkr )

  sendWlkrcount = SIZE( W % R( :, :, sendFrstWlkr : sendlstWlkr ) )
  recvWlkrcount = SIZE( W % R( :, :, recvFrstWlkr : recvlstWlkr ) )

  IF( send == rank ) RETURN

  ASSOCIATE( sendWalkers => W % R( :, :, sendFrstWlkr : sendlstWlkr ) , &
             recvWalkers => W % R( :, :, recvFrstWlkr : recvLstWlkr ) ) 

    CALL MPI_SEND( sendWalkers, sendWlkrcount, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, send, calls, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr ) 

    CALL MPI_RECV( recvWalkers, recvWlkrcount, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, recv, calls, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierr )  

  END ASSOCIATE

END SUBROUTINE mix_walkers
```

Comment: Step 1 in debugging Fortran+MPI programs is to toss out `include 'mpif.h'` and to insert `use mpi` (possibly even `use mpi_08`) and get the compiler to do the first sanity check of your code.  I'd also like to be sure that the subroutine definition is inside a scope where `implicit none` is in effect.  And I can imagine all sorts of errors in the code you don't show us which would elicit the symptoms you report.

Comment: The problem is when I replace 'mpif.h' with use mpi, although Intel compiles, mpifort has a compile error "Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_recv’" and I don't have Intel on the HPC

Comment: This is a legit error since `status` does not have the right type (!)

Comment: Technically status does have the correct type - the problem is it doesn't have the correct rank. Implicit None would be nice as well

Comment: `status` should be an array of `MPI_STATUS_SIZE` integers. You are setting up your program for stack corruption upon receive, which may result in anything ranging from local variables changing values out of nowhere to program crashes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MPI_SEND is blocking. It is not guaranteed to return until the process which is being sent to posts a corresponding receive. In the code you have all the recieves may never be reached as the process may be waiting in the send. To fix this investigate MPI_ISEND/MPI_IRECV and MPI_WAIT, or MPI_SENDRECV.

For more details see section 3.4 in the MPI standard at https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf